# TYPO3 Custom Element colorpicker

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, fluid-styled-content

I'm new to TYPO3 (first project) and I have some understanding issues of the creation of a custom element with a colorpicker. In this project I already have created a few elements but I only use predetermined fields for the backend input. For the element I need next I need the user to choose a color. I haven't found a fitting existing element. My setup that doesn't work is in the `TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` file and looks like this.

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']=array();            
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['label']='Color';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']=array();
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['type']='input';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['renderType']='colorpicker';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['size']=10;

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['wo_mitem'] = array(
    'showitem' => '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
        header;Title,
        subheader;Background,
        header_link;Target,
        item_0;Color,
        bodytext;Text;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]
        ');
```

The `item_0` was a try to create a colorpicker but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need something different in a different file? The first few lines I added to define my field. Is there a better way to do this?

All other files in my custom extension work (since all other custom elements work fine). The only difference is, as said, the need of a way to choose a color in the new one.

Just for a clearer look here the other files

setup.txt:

```
lib.contentElement {
  templateRootPaths {
    100 = EXT:wostyle/Resources/Private/Template
  }
}
tt_content {
    wo_mitem < lib.contentElement
    wo_mitem {
        templateName = MItem
    }
}
```

tt_content.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
   array(
      'WO_Item (ItemBox, Text only)',
      'wo_mitem',
      'content-image'
   ),
   'CType',
   'wostyle'
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']=array();            
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['label']='Farbe';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']=array();
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['type']='input';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['renderType']='colorpicker';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['item_0']['config']['size']=10;

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['wo_mitem'] = array(
            'showitem' => '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
            header;Bezeichnung,
            subheader;Chemische Bezeichnung,
            header_link;Zielseite,
            item_0;Farbe,
            bodytext;Text;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]
            ');
```

typo.ts

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.wo_extra {
   header = WO Elemente
   after = common
  elements {
    wo_mitem {
         iconIdentifier = content-image
         title = WO_Item (ItemBox, Text only)
         description = Ein Produktfeld mit Text
         tt_content_defValues {
            CType = wo_mitem
         }
      }
   }
   show := addToList(wo_mitem)
}
```

MItem.html

```
<div class="item-text">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{data.header_link}">
        <div class="item-front">
            <f:if condition="{data.subheader}!=''">
            <f:then>
            <div class="item-bg">
                <f:format.html>{data.subheader}</f:format.html>
            </div>
            </f:then>
            </f:if>
            <div class="item-title">
                <f:format.html>{data.header}</f:format.html>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-back">
            <f:format.html>{data.bodytext}</f:format.html>
        </div>
    </f:link.typolink>
</div>
<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>
```

EDIT: I use typo3 8.7.8

Answer (score 2):

I did not check your whole code but I have a working color-picker on a field ...
you're close but an error that pops up right away is that your item should be placed under **`['columns']`** ...

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['item_0']=array();
```

next you are missing the refference to the wizard !! (you should adopt the annotation with square brackets which shows much more the structure)

this should be stored in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`: *(when you override existing fields, otherwise you have a dedicated code for the element)*

```
<?php

/***************
 * Modify the tt_content TCA
 */
$tca = [
    'columns' => [
        'item_0' => [
            'label' => 'Color',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 10,
                'eval' => 'trim',
                'default' => '#ffffff',
                'wizards' => [
                    'colorChoice' => [
                        'type' => 'colorbox',
                        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_wizards:colorpicker_title',
                        'module' => [
                            'name' => 'wizard_colorpicker'
                        ],
                        'dim' => '20x20',
                        'JSopenParams' => 'height=600,width=380,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'] = array_replace_recursive($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'], $tca);
```

Comment: Tank you very much, now it works. The "columns" was missing and also the item_0 field in the table itself. :)

Comment: Its depractecated in TYPO3 8: New use:   'renderType' => 'colorpicker', see here for more: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Deprecation-79440-TcaChanges.html

Answer (score 1):

With the help of webMan and some internet searches I could adopt my code a little.
I added the file "ext_tables.sql" with the content

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    item_0 varchar(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
);
```

And changed the tt_content.php in TCA/Overrides to:

```
$temporaryColumns = Array(
    "item_0" => Array(
        'label' => 'Color',
        'config' => Array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'colorpicker',
            'size' => 10
        )
    )
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content',$temporaryColumns);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['wo_mitem'] = array(
            'showitem' => '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
            header;Bezeichnung,
            subheader;Chemische Bezeichnung,
            header_link;Zielseite,
            item_0;Farbe,
            bodytext;Text;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]
            ');
```

There are still a view things missing in compare to webMans code but at least this is the first working version I have so i figured i show it since my question is answered:).

Comment: In TYPO3 12 the `renderType=colorpicker` will be replaced by TCA type `color`. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Color/Index.html when the time comes.